# How to get canvas cursor click coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hi i have this function that I found on this website.

```
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
}
```

My question is, how do I pass an event as an argument. I want to call this function inside the canvas click event.

```
document.getElementById('puzzle').onclick = function(e) {
  //Call it here
};
```

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried `getCursorPosition($(this),e)`, if `('puzzle')` is your canvas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing your canvas has an ID puzzle:

```
document.getElementById('puzzle').onclick = function(e) {
    getCursorPosition(this, e)
};
```

The event is passed to the function as e (which is almost always short for event).